# Using an attribute of an object as a default parameter in a function inside a class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write the implement of BST in OOP style.I got some bugs while writting insertNode function like

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘BST::root’
```

.How can i fix it?

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node(){}
    node(int data){
        this->data=data;
        this->left=NULL;
        this->right=NULL;
    }
};
struct BST{
    node* root;
public:
    BST(){root=NULL;}
    node*& getRoot(){return root;}
    void insert(int data,node*& t=this->root){
        if(!t){
            t=new node(data);
            return;
        }
        if(t->data<data) insert(data,t->left);
        else insert(data,t->right);
    }
};
```

Comment: You cant do this.

Comment: Sure you can... Just overload insert (two insert functions) to take one arg and call the other form with root as second arg.  Also if you getRoot, you might as well make root public.